# Glide wont load all images in ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-glide

So I have a RecyclerView with a custom adapter and I use Glide to download images from a URL when applicable. Relevant code snippet here:

```
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            final Location location = mLocations.get(position);

            holder.title.setText(location.getTitle());

            if (location.hasImage()) {
                String imageUrl = NetworkHelper.getImageUrl(getContext(),location.getImageName());

                holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                // Use Glide for image loading
                Glide.with(getContext())
                        .load(imageUrl)
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .into(new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(holder.image) {
                            @Override
                            public void onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
                            super.onLoadFailed(e, errorDrawable);
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                            @Override
                            public void onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, GlideAnimation<? super GlideDrawable> animation) {
                                super.onResourceReady(resource, animation);
                            }
                        });
            } else {
                // Due to the nature of the RecyclerView, we need to ensure we clear
                // out images to odd behavior.
                Glide.clear(holder.image);
                holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }
```

Problem is that the onResourceReady() method isnt always being called and hence not all images being loaded. Ive verified all the URL's being passed and they all seem fine. Is there a Glide specific issue here perhaps? If I take a URL that is not being loaded and hard code it into the imageUrl variable, its still not being downloaded, so there must be something specific to those images thats causing glide to fail. A timeout issue perhaps?

EDIT: I added the onLoadFailed method and it does hit, but the Exception is null, which is kinda weird. Basically same issue as described here: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/741

Comment: Pass context from activity/fragment to adapter.

Comment: See my updated question. onLoadFailed does trigger, but the Exception is null...